# Pointers to objects in function scope

Tags: c++, pointers, function

When you create some pointers inside the scope of a function, what happens when the function goes out of scope?  Do they get destroyed or should I call delete on them at some point?

```
void XMLDocument::AddNode(XMLNode& node)
{
    std::string val = node.GetNodeName();
    TiXmlElement* el = new TiXmlElement(val.c_str());  // What about this object ptr?
    TiXmlText * txt = new TiXmlText(node.GetNodeValue().c_str());  // And this one?
    el->LinkEndChild(txt);
    document.LinkEndChild(el);
}
```

Comment: `<mantra>` Use smart pointers. `</mantra>`

Comment: Is this a general question, or specific to `TinyXml` usage?  The correct answer depends on that.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you need to call `delete` on both the pointers in order to avoid memory leaks. But in you case, it looks like you are putting this pointer in a `document` object (I am assuming `document` stores the *pointer* itself and will not create *copy* of the pointed to object itself). So if you call `delete` here, the pointer you have given to the `document` object will be invalid one. So if `document` object takes ownership of deleting the memory you allocated in this function, then you should not call `delete` here, else if it is creating the copy of the object you passed, then you need to `delete` it here. Using a smart pointer will be quite useful in these type of scenarios. Take a look at [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) for more details.

Comment: don't think so I think op is asking about the pointers to objects created using new

Answer (score 1):

When you use new, memory from the heap is allocated, while the objects locally declared in a function are allocated on the stack.
The objects allocated to the stack stop to exist after the method call.
In your case  `TiXmlElement* el` is a pointer allocated on the stack that references memory on the heap. Once you leave the function, the `el` pointer will stop to exist (since it was on the stack) but the memory that it referenced, still exists (was on the heap). So if that memory is not "freed", it is considered as "leaked"

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can be stated for sure is that immediately after the exit of this function, neither of those pointers has been returned to the heap.

What happens after the function exits depends on the contract for memory usage that is implied by passing a pointer into `LinkEndChild`.  Do you still own the memory after this, or does it get cleaned up when the new parent (in this case `document`, which accesses the memory directly for `el`, and via `el` for `txt`) is cleaned up?  If the former, then you are correct not to `delete` it.  If the latter, then at some point you need to clean it up, presumably after `document` (global? class member?) is done with.

A further nuance is what is the contract on construction of `TiXmlElement` and `TiXmlText` - do they copy the input C-string, or use them by reference?

I would guess that it's `XmlDocument`'s doc to clean up all memory that is linked into the document. Kind of messy, though.  Check the destructor `XmlDocument::~XlmDocument`, see if it walks a list of children cleaning them up (recursively).

EDIT: This looks like TinyXML, in which case it's supposed to clean up all the memory you give it on destruction.  See here for a discussion : http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=518023

> The semantics of TinyXML clearly imply
>   that (a) it owns the document tree,
>   and (b) you pass in nodes that you
>   allocate. I can see no good argument
>   for it not simply using the delete
>   operator on everything linked into it.
>
> EDIT: In fact, given that TinyXML (or
>   at least the copy I have here) clearly
>   has `while ( node ) { temp = node; node
>   = node->next; delete temp; }` in the TiXMLNode destructor, I'm guessing
>   this is just a bug in the TinyXML++
>   wrapper.

See also previous Stack Overflow question about TinyXml memory management [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853559/what-memory-management-do-i-need-to-cleanup-when-using-tinyxml-for-c).

> The [documentation for LinkEndChild](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#5d29442ae46de6d0168429156197bfc6)
>   says this:
>
> NOTE: the node to be added is passed
>   by pointer, and will be henceforth
>   owned (and deleted) by tinyXml. This
>   method is efficient and avoids an
>   extra copy, but should be used with
>   care as it uses a different memory
>   model than the other insert functions.